# Displaying searched record for a query using 'like' at the top in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am writing a search query which makes a search based on first name and last name.
The query is like this:

```
select fname,lname 
from users 
where fname like fname like '%$name%' or lname like '%$name%';
```

if the user enters first name and last name in the search box,I have exploded it with a 'space' and the query goes like this

```
select fname,lname 
from users 
where fname like fname like '%$f_name%' or lname like '%$l_name%';
```

In the second query if I enter **John Thomas**,it shows me all the records with John or Thomas in first or last name,but the actual search result i.e John Thomas(**exact match**) is somewhere below in the results.(If I have 100 results its on the 60th position).

How can I modify the query to achive this or do I have to handle it programatically? i.e Check the result array and match the check box value for its presence and display it fist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT fname, lname FROM users 
WHERE (fname = '$f_name' AND lname = '$l_name') 
OR (fname LIKE '%$f_name%') OR (lname LIKE '%$l_name%');
```

And if you need to order then `ORDER BY lname, fname` in the end of the query, depending on what you need to order by of course.

Comment: Thanks I am using the same currently.Just I use like in the 'and' part is well. :) I was looking for some solution where in the OR query should work and I should get the exact match at the top.But not sure if its possible.

Answer (score 1):

ADD in query

```
ORDER BY `fname`
```

You can testing mysql sorting
More information here ==> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html